# Android xml: Problem setting size and attributes of custom title bar

Tags: android, xml

I have been struggling with this problem for 2 days. And when I thought I got the solution, it turned out that it is not the best solution.

My problem is I want to use a custom title bar in order to add a button to the title bar. I solve this by using android:windowTitleStyle. But then I realised that depending on the Theme I used, the size of title text is different and unchangable. The text size I set in my custom title layout is IGNORED.

Knowing this I thought I would also have to set text size as a Theme attribute as well. And found an answer on this site that did this. However my problem was not solved. I ended up setting the text style for every text view in app.

What I want is to set only the custom title bar text properties, and make every other text view be INDEPENDENT of these attributes.

Comment: don't style it, but instead inflate a custom view.

Comment: I dont understand.

Comment: @Martin I got some good rest and checked back the reference. It was a style and not  a layout. I was passing a layout to it which it silently ignored and gave me rubbish instead. Now I got that part right and now I must dump custom title and use an action bar instead.